# getting some warnings on cocos2d can any body tell me how to solve these

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone, levelhelper

i developed the game using levelHelper game is working fine but i am getting some error or some kind of warnings in the logs which are

> 2013-03-07 12:59:59.744 RobotRunner[3970:c07] cocos2d: **** WARNING
>   **** CC_ENABLE_GL_STATE_CACHE is disabled. To improve performance, enable it by editing ccConfig.h
>
> 2013-03-07 12:59:59.745 RobotRunner[3970:c07] cocos2d: cocos2d v2.0.0
>   2013-03-07 12:59:59.745 RobotRunner[3970:c07] cocos2d: Using Director
>   Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
>
> 2013-03-07 12:59:59.761 RobotRunner[3970:c07] Retina Display Not
>   supported
>
> 2013-03-07 12:59:59.765 RobotRunner[3970:c07] cocos2d: animation
>   started with frame interval: 60.00
>
> 2013-03-07 12:59:59.766 RobotRunner[3970:c07] cocos2d: surface size:
>   480x320
>
> 2013-03-07 12:59:59.767 RobotRunner[3970:c07] cocos2d: CCTexture2D:
>   Using RGB565 texture since image has no alpha
>
> 2013-03-07 13:00:00.905 RobotRunner[3970:c07] cocos2d:
>   CCSpriteBatchNode: resizing TextureAtlas capacity from [29] to [40].

can any body tell me how to solve these things and why it's showing

Answer (score 1):

Only the first is a warning you can fix. It tells you how to do so.

The rest are just noise from cocos2d.

Answer (score 0):

These are not warnings, these are informational\debug messages.